# Arithmetic in tabular lengths ( p{...} )

Tags: tables, macros, arithmetic

I'm trying to do some simply arithmetic for a dynamic column type in `tabularx`.
What I want is to be able to calculate *(n-1)* * *X*. I tried to use the `calc` package, but I just cant figure it out.

```
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{%
    |>{\hsize=\dimexpr#1\hsize + {#1-1} * 2 * \tabcolsep + {#1-1} * \arrayrulewidth\relax}X|%
}
```

This `columntype` is suppose to be a part of a bigger function.

```
\newcommand{\DYNcol}[2]{%
    \multicolumn{#1}{Y{#1}}{#2}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping in `\dimexpr` must be done with `()`, not with braces. Integer factors should *follow* a dimension parameter (or precede it without the `*` operator)

```
\dimexpr \hsize * #1 + \tabcolsep * (#1-1) * 2 + \arrayrulewidth\relax
```

Also `#1\hsize` works.